# Schema validation for an optional field which accepts numbers or empty string

Tags: regex, xsd, xsd-validation

I had a field which was mandatory before and i used schema validation as `[0-9]{1,14}` to accept only numbers.

Now, that I have made the same field as optional, I want a schema validation which accepts NUMBERS as well as EMPTY STRING (`""`) or WHITESPACE ONLY string..

What schema validation should I use in .XSD?

Comment: use :- `[0-9]{0,14}`..one more thing, try to understand the regex you are using..don't blindly copy it

Comment: @rock321987 now, after i made changes as u said I understood it completely and it's working as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: @rock321987 could you please tel me in case if I want it to accept a white space as well along with numbers and empty string,what changes i have to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 1 with 0.

```
"[0-9]{0,14}"
```

`{0,14}` repeats the previous token from 0 upto 14 times.

Comment: ThankYou so much, It's working... Can u please let me know in case if I want it to accept a white space as well,what changes i have to make?

Comment: `"[0-9 ]{0,14}"` or `"[0-9\\s]{0,14}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternation like:

```
(\d{1,14}|\s*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT7zK2/1)

This will allow 1 to 14 digits or an empty/ whitespace only string (`\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace characters).

Since XSD regex patterns are anchored by default (i.e. the whole pattern is enclosed with `^(` and `)$`) you may just use

```
\d{1,14}|\s*
```